# Easiest way to make comet chat

Tags: php, jquery, comet

I need to make tet-a-tet comet chat with many channels using PHP as a backend and JQuery as a frontend. I need something like event-driven server to do this... But didnt find any simple and appplicable to my task. Please, tell me the best solution for this problem

Answer (score 2):

You may a look for [Reverse Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Ajax) term. Probably the [APE project](http://www.ape-project.org/) will help you.

Comment: Been using APE project for PHP and Python (django) and it works perfect. Server side javascript and got working scripts for mootools, jquery and probably other js-frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a daemon: http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/

Comment: Not very useful as i have not enough time to write a server by myself :) deadline coming soon

Comment: Making daemons is fun. But there are speedier alternatives.

Comment: though it's nice to see my own project (system_daemon) mentioned here, this is not the right tool for the job. i recommend taking a closer look at node.js; and have that (maybe) talk to a php backend.

Answer (score 1):

You could try WebSync On-Demand...there's a simple chat demo that should get you off and running...

http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/demos

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of [AjaxIM](http://ajaxim.com/)?

It's an open-source instant messaging framework that uses AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use node.js. It supports event-driven web servers and there is already a chat demo (http://nodejs.org/#demo). With node.js you write your backend and frontend code in Javascript, so it shouldn't be problem if you know this language.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually just reading an article on this, which led me to: http://demo.java2script.org/gtalk/ which is an example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple example here that can get you started with comet. It covers compiling Nginx with the NHPM module and includes code for simple publisher/subscriber roles in jQuery, PHP, and Bash.

http://blog.jamieisaacs.com/2010/08/27/comet-with-nginx-and-jquery/